# Regex in re_path django 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, regex

The problem with my code is that I keep getting a "page not found (404) error, the path 'post/...' does not match" when I try to click on a hyperlink on my posts page. I made 3 posts. Could it be the regex? Because I'm currently not good at regex.
How can I match the views.py to the correct path in urlpatterns?

My urls.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path

from blog import views as blog_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/', blog_views.post),
    
    re_path(r'^post(.*)/$', blog_views.post),

    path('about/'. blog_views.about),

    path('', blog_views.index),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

My views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Post

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html', {'posts': posts})

def post(request, slug):
    print(slug)
    return render ('post.html',{'post': get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})
```

Comment: You have `re-path` rather than `re_path`. Not sure if this is the whole problem, but it needs fixing.

Comment: You haven't even explained what the error is.

Comment: I've edited and corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `path()` syntax and get slug easy

```
path('post/<slug:slug>/',  blog_views.post),
```

If you still want to use re_path you should write pattern group  as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)

```
re_path(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$', views.year_archive),
```

or you can use even more restrictive slug regex

```
[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*
```

Comment: I've tried your solutions but I'm getting a TypeError->join() argument must be str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not 'dict'